# Share Resources Among Multiple Android Source Sets

Tags: android, android-resources

I am currently working on an Android project with multiple source sets.

My question is concerned with string resources.

The majority of the string resources are in the `main/res/values` directory.

There is an alternative source set called `foo` which overrides some of the string resources in `main/res/values`. This works just fine, however there is an additional source set we can call `foobar` that is a slightly different version of `foo`.

Is there a way `foobar` can be configured to use the resources defined in `foo/res/values` instead of defaulting back to `main/res/values`? Despite the source sets both being slightly different, the resources between `foo` and `foobar` are to be identical so I'd only like to write them once.

Essentially in `foobar` if I try to get the string resource `cat` I want it to look in `foo/res/values/string.xml` as if I was making the resource reqeust in `foo`; and just like in `foo`; fallback to `main/res/values` if that resource isn't defined.

Is there a way that I can structure my project to have this behavior? I am limited in how much I can restructure the source sets within the project, so I understand that the problem I am presenting might go against some conventional practices.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was to add the following to my application's build.gradle

```
android.sourceSets {
    foobar.res.srcDirs = ['src/foo/res']
}
```